# Set log level info dynamically by environment to log4j with spring-boot-starter-log4j2

Tags: spring, log4j2, environment, log-level

I would like to set the log level info depending on the environment (develop, stage, prod), in a spring app. I tried creating different log4j.xml files and setting in the application.proopreties the configuration required for each env. For instance for stage I did `logging.config=classpath:stage/log4j.xml`, this in the application-stage.properties.

The program compiles correctly and the files are found. I have a different log level for each env. The problem is that I'm not seeing anything in the logs. I think Spring is using the file which is located in the `classpath:log4j.xml` path, because when I had a log4j.xml in this path the logs were printed with the level defined in it, and thereafter when I deleted this file, the app stoped to print the logs. I'm not pretty sure if is possible to configure this in the application.properties file and I need to do something different.

Comment: try moving log4j configs to application.properties only

Comment: A log4j 1 xml file will of course not configure log4j2. The name is different. lso if it is only levels you can do that from the `application.properties` instead of a seperate config. Just add `logging.level.root=DEBUG` or whatever you like to the environment specific application.properties.